# Cannot pass a list to dplyr filter using %in%

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I am unable to pass a list to dplyr's `filter()` function using `%in%` and I don't know why it's not working.

**I recreated the problem below:**
I have two datasets, `x` and `y`.

`x` is set of origin IDs (`O_ID`) and destination IDs (`D_ID`).
A single `O_ID` in `x` can be associated with multiple `D_ID's`.

`y` is a set of coefficients for the `D_IDs`.

I want to take all the `D_IDs` associated with a particular `O_ID`, and get the table of coefficients linked to that D_ID. In the example below, that means I want to return the y set with only the rows for `gt` and `st`.

**Sample Code**

```
library(tidyverse)

# setup sample x dataframe
x <- data.frame("O_ID" = c("A1","A1","A2","B1","B1","B2"),
                "D_ID" = c("gt","st","hy","kl","st","nu"))
# setup sample y dataframe
y <- data.frame("ID" = c("gt","st","hy"),
                "coef_1" = c(2.6,1.8,6.7),
                "coef_2" = c(5.6,2.1,3.6))

# get D_ID's associated with O_ID == "A1"
x_A1 <- x %>%
          filter(O_ID == "A1") %>%
          select(D_ID) %>%
          as.list()

# FAILED STEP:
# get table of coefficients for D_IDs
y_A1 <- y %>%
          filter(ID %in% x_A1)
```

Why isn't my final step working? Is a list the right format to pass the info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `pull` instead of `as.list()` because you want to filter on a `vector` instead of a `list`:

```
# get D_ID's associated with O_ID == "A1"
x_A1 <- x %>%
  filter(O_ID == "A1") %>%
  select(D_ID) %>%
  pull()

# get table of coefficients for D_IDs
y_A1 <- y %>%
  filter(ID %in% x_A1)
```